# Calling server side function from client side not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Here **page1ClientSideFn()** is a client side function of **Page.aspx**. In this function I want to call the server side method **page2ServerSideFn()** of another page **Page2.aspx.cs**. Is there any problem with the below client side code? It's not working. Should I modify the ajax

```
function page1ClientSideFn() {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Page2.aspx.cs/page2ServerSideFn",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {   
         alert("success");
      },
      Error: function () {
         alert("Error");
      }
   });
   }
```

Comment: include method signature for `page2ServerSideFn()`

Comment: make sure to have the attribute [WebMethod] above page2ServerSideFn

Comment: [WebMethod] is there...above the server side function

Comment: `url: "Page2.aspx.cs/page2ServerSideFn"` is incorrect change it to this `url: "~/Page2.aspx/page2ServerSideFn"` Will only work if Page2 is at root. If it is inside any folder add the folder name beforehand like `url: "~/[FolderName]/Page2.aspx/page2ServerSideFn"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url looks wrong.It should not be page codebehind file.`url: "Page2.aspx/page2ServerSideFn",`

Also ensure `page2ServerSideFn` is **public** and **static** method.You can use chrome dev toolbar network tab to monitor your resquest you are sending.

[image: Please follow below basic ajax post]

Comment: If it helped please dont forget to maek it as answer for future readers